# How do I connect to IBM Cloud Databases for Redis using Node.js?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am unable to connect to a [IBM Cloud Databases for Redis](https://www.ibm.com/cloud/databases-for-redis) instance from a [Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) application. I have provisioned an instance and create service credentials, which gives me a connection string.

Using this connection string with the [Node.js client library for Redis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/redis) throws the following connection error:

```
Error: Redis connection to <id>.databases.appdomain.cloud:port failed - read ECONNRESET
  at TCP.onread (net.js:657:25) errno: 'ECONNRESET', code: 'ECONNRESET', syscall: 'read'
```

If I set the `tls` property in the client constructor, I get the following error:

```
Error: Redis connection to <id>.databases.appdomain.cloud:port failed failed - self signed certificate in certificate chain
    at TLSSocket.onConnectSecure (_tls_wrap.js:1055:34)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:182:13)
    at TLSSocket._finishInit (_tls_wrap.js:635:8) code: 'SELF_SIGNED_CERT_IN_CHAIN'
```

This is the code used to create instance of the client library.

```
const redis = require("redis"),
const url = 'rediss://<URL_FROM_SERVICE_CREDS/'
const client = redis.createClient(url);
```

This works fine with a local instance of Redis but not the IBM Cloud Databases version?

Answer (score 0):

IBM Cloud Databases for Redis [uses TLS connections](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/databases-for-redis?topic=databases-for-redis-external-app#driver-tls-and-self-signed-certificate-support) to secure access to all database instances. The TLS connection uses a [self-signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) for authentication. Since the certificate is self-signed, it cannot be trusted by the Node.js runtime without providing the public certificate from the service.

The `connection.rediss.certificate.certificate_base64` value from the service credentials provides a Base64 encoded string containing the certificate file. This string can then be used with the Node.js client library as follows...

```
const ca = Buffer.from(cert_base64, 'base64').toString('utf-8')
const tls = { ca };
const client = redis.createClient(url, { tls });
```

The tls property is passed through to the `tls.connect` method in Node.js, which is used to setup the TLS connection. This method supports a `ca` parameter to extend the trusted CA certificates pre-installed in the system. By providing the self-signed certificate using this property, the errors above will not be seen.